# What is the natural life span of a Clone?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

In Star Wars, the Clones are introduced in the story "Attack of the Clones". In this story it was explained that they were bred from the genetic template of Jango Fett. They underwent an accelerated growth to prepare them for battle in a reasonable time. My question is, after this do the clones age naturally or are they do they effectively not age?

Comment: Ah, what the hell, I don't got that long a lifespan anyway…

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### They age faster than normal throughout their lifetime

In the canon novel [*Tarkin*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tarkin_(novel)), Vader questions a clone trooper's ability to continue on active duty five years after the Clone Wars (in 14 BBY) due to his rapid aging:

> When the stormtrooper operating the equipment accidentally allowed the
>   flattened sphere to bang against the edge of the cargo hold’s
>   retracted hatch, Vader stamped forward with his gloved hands clenched.
>
> “I warned you to be careful!” he shouted up at the trooper.
>
> “My apologies, Lord Vader. Wind shear from—”
>
> “Excuses won’t suffice, Sergeant Crest,” Vader cut him off. **“Perhaps you are aging too quickly to remain on active duty.”**
>
> Tarkin couldn’t make sense of the remark until **he realized that Crest’s was a face he had seen countless times during the war—the face of an original Kamino clone trooper.** The bare-headed others comprising Vader’s squad were human regulars who had enlisted after the war.
>
> <sub>**p. 94**</sub>

---

The fact that the clones age faster than normal throughout their lives was also confirmed out-of-universe in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=J_6zOjTrI5w#t=176) by [Pablo Hidalgo](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Pablo_Hidalgo) of the [Lucasfilm Story Group](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lucasfilm_Story_Group), which is in charge of *Star Wars* canon. Hidalgo explained that the clones were phased out and replaced with non-clone humans in the Stormtrooper Corps *because the clones age at twice the normal rate*. The relevant quote transcribed from the video is:

> [...] 5 years before the events of Episode IV. By that time the clone operations that the Republic started for the Clone Wars -- they've been phased out. Clone troopers age at like twice the rate of normal people [...]

Comment: that may not be solid evidence though, Vader may just be being a dark lord jerk. We see Capt. Rex, Wolf, and Gregor in Rebels which is 25ish years post RotS / 5 years prior to ANH, if one considers that they went on duty around age 30 or so, then being 50/60 as Rex appears to be in Rebels, and very capable to boot, doesn't seem to indicate any increased decrepitude

Comment: The light that burns twice as bright burns half as long.

Comment: @void_ptr that extra light must be why they have so much trouble aiming at things :-p. And yes I know these are not clones/they are letting them escape/whatever retcon of the day...

Comment: @NKCampbell Well, then how about a quote from Pablo Hidalgo?

Comment: Does this mean that the Clone army is continually created every few years?

Comment: @jim The clones were in continuous production throughout the Clone Wars in order to build up the numbers in the clone army as the Clone Wars ramped up and replace clones killed in combat. The Clone Wars only lasted for a few years (22 BBY to 19 BBY), so the rapid aging of the clones wasn't really a problem during the Clone Wars. A 10 year old clone in the first batch who was biologically 20 years old would have only been biologically in his late 20s by the end of the Clone Wars (if he survived). The clones' rapid aging was only a factor after production stopped when the Clone Wars ended.